# Using net = require('net') in html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

```
<script>
var net;
try{
     net = require('net');
}catch(e){
    alert(e)
}
</script>
```

It shows this error `ReferenceError: require is not defined`. Should I import any other module?

Comment: `require()` is of node.js, you can't use it in the client-side without libraries such as require.js.

Comment: Also, `net` is a module of node.js, it's not a part of the standards of js... I assume there are similar libraries in the network, you can try Google it.

Comment: Thank you, I had try google already. However i got something like your helping's answer but i still confuse. Thank you by the way.

Comment: `net` implements functionality that a browser doesn't support, like making generic network connections.

Comment: @robertklep i google it a lot. However, i can't find solution.

Comment: @Justapokemontrainer there is no solution if what you are looking for is a way of creating generic network connections in a browser. That's simply not possible. So the question becomes: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @robertklep I try to connect the server for revive some data then show the data in html. That is my goal and I got that data already.

Comment: @Justapokemontrainer more information needed: which server, what specific protocol, what type of data? Please edit your question so it contains what exactly it is you want to do, so other people can help you.

Comment: @robertklep Well, Thank you very much but it's bad for asking you too much. I will find my own way. By the way , thank again.

Comment: @Justapokemontrainer you're not just asking me, you're asking all users of StackOverflow, and most of them are happy to help out!